# How to show that G has a pre hamiltonian circuit if and only if every vertex in G is a root

Tags: graph-theory

Let be $G=(X,U)$.

I have to show that these three following propositions are equivalent:

A) All $G$ summits are roots

B) $G$ is strongly connected.

C) A prehamiltonian circuit exists in $G$.

I have already shown that A) $\leftrightarrow$ B)

To my mind saying that a prehamiltonian circuit exists in $G$ only says that there is a path in an undirected or directed graph that visits each vertex at least once.

This does not imply that all $G$ vertices are roots (a root means that for all vertice $y_i \ne x_i$, $x_i$ is ascending of $y_i$, $x_i$ is ascending means that a directed path from $x_i$ to $y_i$ exists).

Yet, it seems easy to show that B) $\leftrightarrow$ C). So if A)$\leftrightarrow$B) and B)$\leftrightarrow$C) then A)$\leftrightarrow$C)

Thus, how can we show that saying that a pre hamiltonian circuit exists in $G$ circuit  $\Leftrightarrow$  all $G$ vertices are roots.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The systematic mixing of symbols and English is rather annoying. I corrected this in the title, please follow lead for the text of the question.

Comment: A pre-Hamiltonian circuit in a digraph is a directed circuit that visits all but one of the vertices. The theorem that you state is clearly false in general; I suspect that it is supposed to have the additional hypothesis that $G$ is strongly connected, in which case its proof is quite easy.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I don't find such a definition of pre-hamiltonian circuit. Neither in my hangout nor on wikipedia or my book. I had: "on appelle cycle (circuit) préhamiltonien d'un graphe, un cycle (circuit) passant *au moins une fois* par chaque sommet de G. (We call prehamiltonian circuit a circuit with a path that visits at least once each vertices). Yet, you're right on the fact that a strongly connected graph implies that it is hamiltonian. However, I still don't find why A) is equivalent to c).